# ffmpeg vaapi encode causes black bar on the right side

Tags: video, ffmpeg, hevc

I'm trying to transcode an 854x480 h264 mp4 video to an h265 mp4 video using vaapi.

The video does come out nice looking, and is encoded very quickly. But there is a black bar on the right side of the video. If I change my command to upscale to 1280x720 this does not happen.

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel vaapi -hwaccel_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -hwaccel_output_format vaapi -i 1.mp4 -c:v hevc_vaapi -vf scale_vaapi=854:480 -ss 00:00:0.0 -t 10 -maxrate 400 output.mp4
```

Comment: Share the output of `ffmpeg -i output.mp4`

Comment: http://ramennoodles.tk/example.png

Comment: Share the output of `ffmpeg -i output.mp4`

Comment: http://ramennoodles.tk/example2.png

Comment: http://ramennoodles.tk/example3.png

Comment: Please import the results (as text) to the question, not as pictures-of-text. Thank you!

Comment: I cannot do it as text because it is too long.

Comment: Maybe this issue will be solved in mesa: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/-/commit/e62c7e7c6caa6c9531afb694e7952a7fc3ac4401

Answer (score 0):

Are you using AMD hardware?

AFAICS this a bug in using HW-acceleration on AMD. (Ubuntu 20.04, ffmpeg 4.2.4.1, Mesa 20.0.8)

```
[hevc_vaapi @ 0x5644267bf7c0] Driver does not support some wanted packed headers (wanted 0xd, found 0).
[hevc_vaapi @ 0x5644267bf7c0] Driver does not support packed sequence headers, but a global header is requested.
[hevc_vaapi @ 0x5644267bf7c0] No global header will be written: this may result in a stream which is not usable for some purposes (e.g. not muxable to some containers).
[hevc_vaapi @ 0x5644267bf7c0] Cropping information on input frames ignored due to lack of API support.
```

It doesn't happen using software encoding:

So as a workaround use hevc/lib265x instead of hevc_vaapi.

```
 -c:v hevc
```

Comment: "-c:v hevc" worked, but it is missing HW acceleration and is several times slower :-/ i also see the yellow text message "[hevc_vaapi @ 0x5610856a3fc0] Driver does not support some wanted packed headers (wanted 0xd, found 0x1)." ([ffmpeg output](https://bin.disroot.org/?0e6ac64a8795ae89#CUdZ9urWe17YGjnAL8Thxo7neGZ1W8x3mwbE8W38V727)) so please how to hevc AMD HW encode without black bar or remove it post process without recoding? Is this some bug, in some component, where to report it please?